# How to handle nodejs async with mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Community,

I am new at nodejs and now i have a problem i cant solve: The async in javascript/nodejs. How can i handle the following so i can push the usernames to the array?

I already tried to help myself with many different functions but nothing works for me... :/

Sincerely Adhskid.

```
function getCurrentBetInformations () {
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `BETS` WHERE BET_ACTIVE = "1" LIMIT 1', function(err, rowss, fields) {

    if (err) logger.warn('MySQL Error: ' + err.stack);

    betid   = rowss[0].BET_ID;
    betends = rowss[0].BET_END;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `BETS_BID` WHERE BID_BET_ID=\'' + betid + '\'', function(err, betbids, fields) {

        if (err) logger.warn('MySQL Error: ' + err.stack);

        var betQuants       = new Array();
        var betIds          = new Array();
        var betUsernames    = new Array();
        var betDates        = new Array();
        var rowsAffected    = betbids.length;

        for(i=0; i < rowsAffected; i++) {
            betQuants.push(betbids[i].BID_KEYS_COUNT);
            betIds.push(betbids[i].BID_ID);
            var betSender = betbids[i].BID_SENDER;
            connection.query('SELECT `USER_NAME` FROM `USER` WHERE `USER_STEAMID` = \'' + betSender + '\' LIMIT 1', function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) logger.warn('MySQL Error: ' + err.stack);

                console.log(rows[0].USER_NAME);
                addUsername(rows[0].USER_NAME);
            });
            function addUsername (currentUsername) {
                betUsernames.push(currentUsername);
            }
            betDates.push(betbids[i].BID_TIME);
            if(betUsernames.length === i) {
                execSiteRef();
            }
        }
        function execSiteRef() {
            console.log(betUsernames);
            sendUserSiteRefresh([betQuants, betIds, betUsernames, betDates], betends);
        }
    }); 
});
```

}

Comment: what is the output you get? any error?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from this part:

```
if(betUsernames.length === i) {
     execSiteRef();
}
```

You should iinstead check if the betUsernames array is of the final size:

```
if(betUsernames.length === rowsAffected) {
     execSiteRef();
}
```

maybe there is more errors though, I did not check closely.

Comment: It didnt change anything :/